# the iphone code optimization problem

Tags: iphone, c++, xcode, optimization

I use XCode develop an App for ipad, the code write in c++

When I use optimization level (None -O0 ) the app run normal ... When I use optimization level (fastest,smallest -Os) the app will crash by one pointer point to an useless address？

What's the problem?

Thanks !

Comment: you need to post the symbolicated crash log of your app, so we can point you in the right direction. Also, when the compiler does optimizations, it will remove methods that it feels are not called.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in your code; somewhere, you will be relying on *undefined behaviour*.  This sort of thing may only cause a problem in certain circumstances, such as changing compiler flags.

You will have to debug your code.

Comment: turning up your compiler warnings is likely to expose several lurking bugs and/or areas for improvement.

Comment: @Alex: It could be any number of things.  You could be overwriting an array and corrupting something on the stack.  Or on the heap.  You could be using an invalid type alias.  Or something else.  I recommend that as a first exercise, try running your program with Valgrind; that should eliminate a whole class of problems.

Comment: have good method for find those bugs ?   I　just use printf to print the value , but I can not find where the pointer have been changed .Thank you